# Physical units manipulation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to have a `units` class/toolbox/package/whatever in MATLAB, which allows me to attach physical units to variables, and to perform unit algebra on them. For example

```
L=0.7; % I want this to become a unit object representing a length in meters
t=0.5; % I want this to become a unit object representing a time in seconds

L=unit.attach(L,'meters');  % just an example, it may work differently
t=unit.attach(t,'seconds');

V=L/t;            % V is now an "unit" object, because it's obtained by dividing two unit objects
V.displayunits    % should output something like 'meters/seconds' or 'm*s^-1'
L+V;              % should give an error: you can't add lengths and velocities 
One=L/L;
One.displayunits % should output something like 'dimensionless'
```

What I described up to now is more dimensional analysis than actual unit conversion (e.g., from meters to feet), but ideally the class should do that too:

```
L.convertunits('feet') % should give 3.2808399*0.7 = 2.29658793 feet
```

Finally, it would be great if the class contained some predefined physical constants of common use, such as for example

```
g;        % 9.807 m*s^-2, acceleration of gravity
```

I've seen there's a huge number of units-related files on FileExchange. Before starting to download and test each one, I'd like to know which one you would suggest.

Comment: There are something similar, but only work in some specified modeling environments (with appropriated toolboxes). You can try looking for Simscape (Physical Modeling i.e) or SimBiology toolboxes ...

Comment: Btw, you can try this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29621-units-conversion-toolbox, and this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35258-unit-converters

Comment: @scmg wow, the first link looks like the actual implementation of what I asked :) The second link seems to be just a bunch of unit conversion functions, but it doesn't implement a dimensional algebra. Thanks!

Comment: as i said in the first comment, Matlab in normal mode works on values and numbers, so if you want the numbers to have their own units, you have to either write your own classes/functions, or work in special modeling environments which require toolboxes installed, and i can just recommend `Simscape` toolbox with `Physical Modeling` ...